# How can I have git track stash in the reflog?

Tags: git

After doing `stash drop`, the dropped stash commits seem to not even appear in the reflog.  Is there anyway I can configure git to save them in a reflog (in case I need to recover them)?

There are a lot of posts on this site about doing that via `fsck`.  But I'd like to enable some type of tracking *beforehand*.

Comment: Personally, I doubt it-- that's not really how I understand reflog to work, and there's no mention of anything in the [`git reflog` reference page](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog). Perhaps somebody will come along and prove me wrong, though.

Comment: From what I understand the stash IS a kind of reflog, stored in `.git/logs/refs/stash` and can be displayed via `git reflog refs/stash`. So what you want is a reflog of a reflog. And I doubt that's possible.

Comment: An alternative would be to stop using the stash, and use branches for temp work. Reflogs will just do their job as normal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible in current Git (2.42). This follows from:

- The stash is a ref: `refs/stash`
- You reference older stash entries via the reflog of that ref
- If you drop all your stashes then `refs/stash` gets deleted as well
- For any ref: if the ref is deleted then so is the associated reflog

Holding onto the reflog file after ref deletion (subject to later pruning) is a [project idea](https://github.com/gitgitgadget/git/issues/236) at this point (apparently no one is working on it).

Answer (score 1):

> How can I have git track stash in the reflog?

In the reflog, you can't, Git tracks the stash list *in* the [`refs/stash`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions#Documentation/gitrevisions.txt-emltrefnamegtemegemmasterememheadsmasterememrefsheadsmasterem) reflog: `git stash list` is `git reflog stash`.

`git stash` is built for a particular workflow. If you want a different workflow, you can use `git stash create` to make a stash set, manage references to your stash sets however you want, and apply what you want with `git stash apply $thatset`

Answer (score 0):

According to Git Documentation...

> If you mistakenly drop or clear stash entries, they cannot be recovered through the normal safety mechanisms. However, you can try the following incantation to get a list of stash entries that are still in your repository, but not reachable anymore.

The documentation provides the following command. I believe this is exactly what you need:

```
git fsck --unreachable | grep commit | cut -d\ -f3 | xargs git log --merges --no-walk --grep=WIP
```

Comment: Let's note however that the final grep will fail to find stash entries with custom messages (except those explicitly using the string "WIP").